# Getting an empty line being formed when day is Sunday (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, date, calendar

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace calendar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int year;
            int day;
            string[] month = new string[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
            int[] days = new int[] { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

            Console.Write("Enter the year for which you wish to generate the calendar >> ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out year); // Validate //

            Console.Write("Enter the day of the week that January first is on >> ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out day); // Validate //
            while (day > 31 || day < 1) // Reprompt for value if date is out of range //
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid date >> ");
                Console.Write("Enter the day of the week that January first is on >> ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out day); // Validate //

            }

            switch (LeapYear(year)) // Switch statement checks if Leap Year is true //
            {
                case true:
                    days[1] += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Calendar for year - {0}", year);
                    for (int i = 0; i < month.Length; i++)   
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + month[i]);
                        day = DisplayCalender(days[i], day);
                        Console.Write("\n");

                    }
                    break; 
            }
        }


            public static int DisplayCalender(int days, int start) //Display Function//
        {
            int startDay = start;

            Console.WriteLine("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
            for (int i = 0; i < start; i++)
                Console.Write("\t");
            for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
            {
                if (startDay > 6)
                {
                    startDay = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.Write(i + "\t");
                startDay++;
            }

            return startDay;

        }
        public static Boolean LeapYear(int year)
        {
            if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0))) // Checks each OR AND statements and return true or false //
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `DateTime` to determine what day of the week January 1st of a particular year is?  Also how can the day of the week be between 1 and 31, shouldn't it be 1 to 7?

Answer (score 1):

I'm imagining the problem you're describing is having a month that starts on Sunday is making the calendar skip an entire line. Like the image:

[image: February 2020]

That is happening because your method `public static int DisplayCalender(int days, int start)` is receiving the parameter `int start` with a value of `7`.
That makes write tabs on the whole week on your first `for` and then skip the line on the second `for`.

To solve the issue you can simply reassign `startDay` with zero when it is `7` and check on you tab loop for `startDay` instead of `start`:

```
public static int DisplayCalender(int days, int start) //Display Function//
{
    int startDay = start == 7 ? 0 : start;
    Console.WriteLine("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
    for (int i = 0; i < startDay; i++)
        Console.Write("\t");

    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        if (startDay > 6)
        {
            startDay = 0;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.Write(i + "\t");
        startDay++;
    }

    return startDay;
}
```

This will give you the expected result:

[image]

**What can you improve from here?**

Making all that from scratch probably made you learn a lot about loop and flow. If you have some time check on [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8).
There you have methods to find leap years, day of the week, and Month. That would help you simplify your code a lot.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

First I must say you are overcomplicating this very much, there is a perfect date library out of the box that you could have used. 
For example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
bool isLeapYear = DateTime.IsLeapYear(now.Year);
int daysInCurrentMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month);
```

Instead of this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
    for (int i = 0; i < start; i++)
        Console.Write("\t");
```

Do this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
    if (start < 7)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < start; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\t");
        }
    }
```

And instead of this:

```
if (startDay > 6)
{
  startDay = 0;
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

do this:

```
        if (startDay > 6)
        {
            startDay = 0;
            if (i!=1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }                    
        }
```

So DisplayCalender method should look like this:

```
public static int DisplayCalender(int days, int start) //Display Function//
{
    int startDay = start;

    Console.WriteLine("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");
    if (start < 7)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < start; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\t");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        if (startDay > 6)
        {
            startDay = 0;
            if (i != 1 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.Write(i + "\t");
        startDay++;
    }

    return startDay;
}
```